# Can you use (max / min) on a mongoose string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Can you use it in this way, so that the maximal string length is 5 Characters, or is this "option" only for Numbers?

```
  someString: {
    type: String,
    max: 5
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for `maxLength`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `min/max` is for `Number` and `Date`. For string, it's `minLength/maxLength`.

More info [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators).